# Polk directories Ishpeming Michigan for the years of 1880-1904?

Tags: united-states, michigan, directories, property-records

I’m looking for specific information on what types of businesses were at a specific address in Ishpeming Michigan. It’s now a printing place but it was built in 1881, I know there’s been many different businesses in this building. How do I figure out what was in the building for the years 1881-1904?